# Get post by dynamic tag and post type

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, tags

I have a custom post type called spotlight. I'm trying to find posts from post type post that is tagged the same tag as whatever spotlight is tagged. Here is my NOT working code. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
function special_loop() { 
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'tag' => '$posttags = get_the_tags();',
));

if($q->have_posts()) : while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    do_action( 'genesis_entry_header' );
endwhile;endif;
}
```

Comment: I also tried 'tag_slug__in' => array( $posttags) but I get Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\localhost\webroot\eh\public_html\wp-includes\formatting.php on line 1571

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it working with:

```
function special_loop() { 
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    //echo $tag->name . ' '; 
      $spotlighttag = $tag->name;
      echo $spotlighttag;
  }
}
$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'tag_slug__in' => array( $spotlighttag), 
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
));

if($q->have_posts()) : while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    do_action( 'genesis_entry_header' );
    echo 'this at least go here';
endwhile;endif; 
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```